# Why is HTML data stripped and only plain text left?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I'm trying to put transformed XML data into an HTML page using an XSL transform. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="w3.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

The contents of XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the transformed XML does not have the HTML attributes; it looks like this:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Here is the function that fills the DOM, is this the cause of the problem:

```
//Load the XML document and XSLT document into XML DOM objects
var xml = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
var xslt = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);

//Set the async property on both documents to false so that they both completely load 
//before any further processing is attempted.
xml.async = false;
xslt.async = false;

//Load XML and XSLT documents into the XML DOM objects.
xml.load("w3.xml");
xslt.load("w3.xsl");

//Create a new XSLTProcessor object and use its importStylesheet() method to import the XSLT DOM object.
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
processor.importStylesheet(xslt);

//Transform the XML to a new XML DOM object with the transformToDocument() method of the XSLTProcessor.
var XmlDom = processor.transformToDocument(xml)

//Create a new XMLSerializer and use it to serialize the new XML DOM object to a string.
var s = new XMLSerializer(); 
var output = s.serializeToString(XmlDom.documentElement);

//The result can then be output to the innerHTML property of any element on the page.
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("xmldata");
outputDiv.innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: The following images show the result of execution: this is how the output should look like http://imgur.com/mzVOp,ilVgj#0 and http://imgur.com/mzVOp,ilVgj#1 is how it looks like after execution.

Comment: I do not recognize the application displaying the HTML, are you sure it renders HTML table attributes?

Comment: That is firefox with firebug add-on. You see the log console in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I think your 'host' HTML page must have a DOCTYPE identifying the HTML as HTML5.

Then, because you're trying to add attributes, such as *bgcolor* that are obsolete in HTML 5 (see [W3C: HTML5 differences from HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/)) they're ignored and therefore not added to the DOM.

Try using style attributes instead - as recommended in the linked page.

The XSLT for the tr element would then look like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
 ...
  <tr style="background-color:#9acd32;"> 
    <th>Title</th> 
    <th>Artist</th> 
  </tr>
 ...
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've found the cause, seems like css caused the error, still debugging it, it's quite obscure.

Comment: @Demego Are you saying the error is unrelated to the fact that you're using attributes described in the HTML5 spec as 'obsolete'?

Comment: yes, it was the CSS properties that altered the table in misleading way, making me think it was the transformation. The obsolete attributes work just fine.